# how to write inline css in react component without using other library?

Tags: reactjs

```
var Mynav = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div /*style="font-size:100px;"*/>this is my nav bar</div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<Mynav />,document.getElementById('nav'));
```

How can i write in the meaning of `/*style="font-size:100px;"*/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an object to the `style` prop:

```
style={{fontSize: '100px'}}
```

Properties are named exactly like the `style` object of DOM elements.

See the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) for more information.

Comment: Super minor but you don't actually need the 'px' you can just do `{{fontSize: 100}}`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example that does some dynamic styling based on a state would look like this:

```
style={{
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   color: this.state.active ? 'green' : 'red',
}}
```